# Why popstate doesn't fire in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser-history

I have this html page. On chrome, if I click several time in Button2 and then click on navigator back button

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function button_onclick(){
    var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
}

function onPopState(){
    console.log("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
}


window.addEventListener('popstate', onPopState, false);

</script>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="button_onclick()">Button 2</button>

</body>

</html>
```

I can see in the console:

```
location: http://somedomain:8080/examples/bar.html, state: {"foo":"bar"}
```

If I try with Firefox I don't see nothing? I tested with Firefow 13.0.1
Pretty annoying if I want to manage history using html5 history API

Answer (score 0):

Found on another question and helped me :

> popstate isn't supposed to be called when you click the link. It's
>   called when the user navigates with the back/forward button.
>
> Everything is working the way it is supposed to.